# Amplitude of an Image

Tags: fft, image-processing, fourier, amplitude

If I take a two dimensional image and conduct a fourier transform on it, I would get a two dimensional matrix of complex values. **If I want to find the amplitude of each value, is that the same as calculating the magnitude of each component, ie Mag(re,im) = sqrt(re^2+im^2)?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see the question here.

But you're right.
On the DFT map of the image, the magnitude / amplitude, etc. are powers of the length of the vector of the complex number.

On more useful visualization to help working with large Dynamic Range is using the log(1 + abs()) on the DFT.

Comment: I was just confused because when searching online I see articles using amplitude and magnitude interchangeable and I was not sure if they were the same

Comment: Indeed, many uses the terms "amplitude spectrum" and "phase spectrum", the first corresponding the magnitude of the complex values